# 3D plot from geometry_msgs/Pose message

Tags: ros, pose, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to make a 3D plot from data collected by a kinect. For this I recorded a bag file and can echo the topic using:

$ rostopic echo mono_depth_odometer/pose

Which outputs a message like this:

```
    ---
header: 
  seq: 66
  stamp: 
    secs: 1373486339
    nsecs: 909821489
  frame_id: /base_link
pose: 
  position: 
    x: 3.7901529439e-05
    y: 5.22536844969e-05
    z: 0.000106685859698
  orientation: 
    x: 7.32867424846e-06
    y: -2.76516487714e-06
    z: -8.7403562356e-06
    w: 0.999999999931
---
```

Now I would like to plot this in 3D. I have succesfully done this before with

```
rxplot --mode=3d topic1 topic2 topic3
```

So now I've tried this with different combinations with no success, for example:

```
$ rxplot --mode=3d mono_depth_odometer/position/x mono_depth_odometer/position/y mono_depth_odometer/position/z
$ rxplot --mode=3d mono_depth_odometer/position.x mono_depth_odometer/position.y mono_depth_odometer/position.z
```

What is the correct way to access the axis data in the message?

Thank you,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67125/3d-plot-from-geometry_msgs/pose-message/) by [Pino](https://answers.ros.org/users/4831/pino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to specify the 'pose' part:

```
 rxplot --mode=3d mono_depth_odometer/pose/pose/position/x mono_depth_odometer/pose/pose/position/y mono_depth_odometer/pose/pose/position/z
```

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pino](https://answers.ros.org/users/4831/pino/) on 2013-07-12**:
Tried this, got this error back:
Invalid topic spec [/mono_depth_odometer/pose/position/x]: 'PoseStamped' object has no attribute 'position'

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-07-12**:
oops, missed that you were echoing "mono_depth_odometer/pose" in that case, see updated answer.

**Comment by [Pino](https://answers.ros.org/users/4831/pino/) on 2013-07-12**:
It now works, thank you. How is it there are two (/pose/pose/) subtopics? I didn't see this in the gometry_msgs/Pose documentation ( http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Pose.html )

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-07-12**:
What is the message type of mono_depth_odometer? I'm not familiar with any packages that publish such a topic. Basically, whatever that message type is, it has a PoseStamped within it, thus geometry_msgs::PoseStamped has a field called header, and a field called pose, with X/Y/Z, and then the ...

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-07-12**:
... depth_odom message is calling the geometry_msgs::PoseStamped "pose" thus, "pose/pose".